# Dapper System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: 'Must declare the scalar variable

Tags: sql-server, dapper

I'm attempting to query for a specific record with an ID and am declaring the value of the ID but am still getting an error.

First I make the call to the db function:

```
specificEntity = await _db_FinancialEntityDb.GetFinancialEntity(id);
```

Then:

```
public Task<FinancialEntity_Model> GetFinancialEntity(int financialEntityID)
{
        string sql = @"select   fe.Id, 
                                fe.EntityTypeID, 
                                fe.Balance, 
                                fe.InterestRate, 
                                fe.OpenDate, 
                                fe.MinimumPayment, 
                                fe.APY, 
                                fe.EntityName, 
                                fe.InitialAmount, 
                                fet.EntityType 
                        from dbo.Financial_Entity fe 
                            left outer join Financial_Entity_Type fet on fe.EntityTypeID = fet.Id 
                        where fe.Id = @financialEntityID";
        
    return _db.LoadDataObject<FinancialEntity_Model, dynamic>(sql, new { Id = financialEntityID });
}
```

And I'm using QueryFirstAsync:

```
var data = await connection.QueryFirstAsync<T>(sql, parameters);
```

But I keep getting this error:

> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: 'Must declare the scalar variable "@financialEntityID".'

Is `QueryFirstAsync` the problem?

Comment: `@financialEntityID` should be `@Id` since that's the name you're passing to Dapper, no?

Comment: @DM thank you, that was it. I thought the name of the variable being passed in would have been sufficient. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Oddly enough, if you would have written `new { financialEntityID }` it would have been OK because by default the fields of anonymous types [take the name of the variable passed to them](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/fundamentals/types/anonymous-types#code-try-1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@financialEntityID should be @Id since that's the name you're passing to Dapper.

When you pass parameters as an anonymous type the property names should match the parameter names. eg

`new { Id = financialEntityID }`

would bind a parameter called `@Id` with the value of `financialEntityID`.